# php readfile() prints the file on the page instead of downloading it

Tags: php

I have a working code for passing a file to a user to download it.But recently i changed my website template to Flat UI desing and now instead of downloading the file it prints it contain to the page footer.

Php code:

```
    $FileToGet = "C:\\test\\test.exe";
if (file_exists($FileToGet )) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($FileToGet));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($FileToGet));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($FileToGet);
    exit;
}
```

What its printing to the footer:

```
MZ����@��� �!�L�!This program cannot be run in DOS mode. $[�������������:�����,������<� �����������+�{����=�����;�����>����Rich���PEL�ЕR�   V<(�p@� ��3\������sp�@pt.text�TV
```

Comment: You cannot send anything more rather than file. No footer, header or anything else. Just file. Also check server for errors.

Comment: there is no errors on the server side.The file is send but rather than downloading it its "echo" -ing or printing to the page.This is not happening if i dont use flat ui template

Comment: I'd assume you're already writing something to the output, so "html" headers are being already sent - so your "header()" calls (in the code snippet above) aren't being used, which is why your file is being printed at the bottom of a page, rather than prompting some sort of 'file download' dialog from the browser.